# WebAuthenticator is not closing the chrome browser when intent in SEND in Xamarin form Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a Xamarin form android application. I am sharing a photo using my Xamarin app.

My requirement is to log in to the app when I share something for 1st time using my app.

For login I am using WebAuthenticator to support OAuth2. This is working fine and redirecting to my app but the google chrome browser is still opened in the back ground . It is not getting closed.

For normal app login it closes the browser but if I share something via my app and login, the bowser did not close. So it looks like when Intent is SEND it never closes the browser.

Added below code for WebAuthenticator authentication

```
 var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(new WebAuthenticatorOptions
            {
                Url = new Uri($"{_baseUrl}"),
                CallbackUrl = new Uri("callback://")
            });
```

WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity code as below.

```
   [Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },      
        DataScheme = "callback")]
    public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
    {
    }
```

Added below in Android manifest file.

```
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>
```

What I am missing so that it is not closing the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue about [WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync not closing Android browser](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1569) on the github.

And this problem was resolved in the Xamarin.Essential nuget package version 1.6. You can try to update the package in your project to the last version.

Comment: Hi Liyun,
Thanks for the reply. I am using 1.75 version and I still the issue only when the INTENT is SEND.

When I share any pic via my Mobile APP and if the APP is not logged in, I am doing the login process. Once log in completes it redirects to my APP, but the chrome is still running in the back ground.

But if I open the APP (with out sharing, just normal open )and continue the log in the process it closes the chrome browser properly.

Comment: You can try to set the WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity's LaunchMode as SingleTask instead of SingleTop. @abanisamal

Comment: And you can also post an new issue on the github. @abanisamal

Comment: Thank you @Liyun . I have tried with LaunchMode as SingleTask but still I see the issue.

Created an issue in github.
https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/2081

Comment: You can follow up it on the github.